# how to do attachments from a specific directory when sending an email

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to add an attachment when I send an email, but I am not sure how. The email works perfectly fine, but it's the adding onto the attachment for the email which doesn't work. I'm not trying to use any specific platform and just sending it via through the console essentially. I tried msgObj.attachments1.add(...) but it didn't work with it.

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.10.101.10", 500))
                        {
                            client.EnableSsl = false; 
                            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);// has username and password credentials doesnt contain actual username and pass
                            MailMessage msgObj = new MailMessage();
    
                        List<string> attachments1 = new List<string>();
    
                         attachments1.Add(@"C:\Users -test.xlsx");
                       
    
                        msgObj.IsBodyHtml = true; //always sets true, if the body contains html it turns text to html
                      
                        msgObj.To.Add(Destination);
                            msgObj.From = new MailAddress("test@mail.com"); //you can send emails on behalf of somebody
                            msgObj.Subject = YourMessageSubject;
                           // msgObj.Body = YourMessageBody; //need to edit the body remember to use the message body to call upon it
                            msgObj.Body = messageBody2;   //html
                        
                            client.Send(msgObj); // sends the message
                        
                        }
    
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("somethings broken");
                    }
```

Comment: I haven't seen you add it to ```msgObj```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attaching it:

```cs
msgObj.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users -test.xlsx"));
```